# Combining bs-popover and SVG sprites

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to add `bs-popover` functionality to my D3 graph. Each node is displayed as an icon taken from a large sprite sheet, using something like:

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <image id="sprite" xlink:href="sprite.png" width="700" height="1500"></image>
        <symbol id="icon1"
                    viewBox="1 174 60 60"
                    preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <use xlink:href="#sprite"></use>
        </symbol>
    </defs>

    <use xlink:href="icon1" x="30" y="30" width="60" height="60"></use>
</svg>
```

The icons are displayed properly, with a size of 60x60, as defined in the viewBox property of the symbol element.

However, when I inspect the icon in Chrome, I can see that even though only the viewBox of 60x60 is displayed, the entire 700x1500 area of the original image is "reserved".

This causes a problem for me when using the `<bs-popover>` tag, as its position seems to be calculated automatically by the parent element dimensions.

Is there a way to define that the size of the image for `bs-popover` purposes is different? Or even set the popover placement manually?